# System calls that manage directories

Tags: linux, system-calls, directory

In order to implement some security measures in a User-mode-Linux kernel, I am trying to edit system calls, such as opendir and readdir, that would control directories so that I can guarantee a certain directory that can't be reached. Where can I find a list of all system-calls that interact with directories?

Comment: Here is a list of of system calls: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html

Comment: You don't describe enough what exact security measures you are dreaming about....

Comment: So here my plan: I have a directory that I don't want anybody to access (except for the one with the password) and I want to do it as a part of the OS services. If I can edit all system calls that interact with directories in User Mode Linux to respect my intentions, then things will be straight forward.
What I need is a list of these system calls.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the right way to go about it. There are too many candidates. In principle, the number is infinite, since random loadable modules can do anything they want. (Are you controlling what modules get loaded?) You are better off catching this at the common routines which handle that access inside the kernel.

Comment: I would like to edit system calls that only affect the main disk, nothing related to the modules added. And why would the number be infinite if the number of system calls is limited for a kernel?

Comment: After searching a bit, system calls under "fs/open.c" in Linux seems the one(s).

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider the opposite approach, to be notified when some sensitive files or directories are accessed?

Then you would want to use [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify). So start reading [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) (and the syscall man pages referenced there).

Perhaps [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) could also be relevant.